# After progressbar load website is not loading in android webview

Tags: java, android, webview, progress-bar, mobile-development

In my webview application start with progress bar after progress bar hide screen is totally black and not loading website in android webview hedgehog version.

Here is my MainActivity.java code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String websiteURL = "https://xxxxxxxxx.com";
    private WebView webview;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this))//returns true if internet available
        {//if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//Toast.makeText(this,”No Internet Connection, Chris”,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)//alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection available")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you’re Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton(“No”, null)
                    .show();
        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview  = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
             webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
             //ChromeClient is used for select file from gallery
             webview.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
             webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
             webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
             webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
        }//Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webview.reload();
              }
        });
    }
    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            //@Override//Keep webview in app when clicking links
            if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            else if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
                /*view.loadUrl(url);*/
                return false;
            }
            /*else if (url.startsWith("intent")) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                    String fallbackUrl = intent.getStringExtra("browser_fallback_url");
                    if (fallbackUrl != null) {
                        view.loadUrl(fallbackUrl);
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    //not an intent uri
                }
                return true;
            }*/
            // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
            // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
            if ( url.contains(".pdf")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
                try{
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    //user does not have a pdf viewer installed
                }
            } else {
                webview.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return false; // then it is not handled by default action
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            /*mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);*/
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e("error",description);
        }
    }//set back button functionality
    public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    //Log.e(Common.TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            Uri[] results = null;
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = null;
                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {//if user presses the back button do this
        if(webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) {//check if in webview and the user can go back
            webview.goBack();//go back in webview
        }else
        {//do this if the webview cannot go back any further
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)//alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("EXIT")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
    }
}
class CheckNetwork {private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();
    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(info == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
            return false;}
        else{
            if(info.isConnected()){
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available…");
                return true;
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:max="3"
            android:progress="100"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"/>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```